# Disable feature simplification

Tags: geoserver

So I've created a store linked to a PostGIS-enabled backend and I've explicitly disabled on the fly simplification. Everything was running as expected until I added a few more SLDs for a few layers. All of a sudden , GeoServer started simplifying the geometries and that creates a huge problem since I have whole areas that are being simplified away.

I'm accessing these layers through a WMS query that fetches a layer group. Doing individual layer previews still returns simplified geometries.

I've looked into the datastore.xml file and the simplify option is set to false. At this point I'm completely clueless as to how to force-disable simplification , or at least control the manner in which simplification is being applied.

EDIT:
On the front-end , I'm accessing the WMS endpoint through an OpenLayers app , like so

```
mapLayer: new ImageLayer({
    source: new ImageWMSSource({
        url: "http://10.10.10.12:8080/geoserver/wms",
        params: {"LAYERS": "vimars:baseChart"},
        serverType: "geoserver"
    })
  })
```

No additional query parameters are being passed or altered. When the map gets rendering and the WMS request gets fired , this shows up in my GeoServer logs

```
2020-02-13 14:31:46,963 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=vimars%3AbaseChart&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A198&WIDTH=5710&HEIGHT=2855&BBOX=43.14008315823114%2C27.77344470081666%2C43.25146798108994%2C27.996214346534245'; against '/web/**'
2020-02-13 14:31:46,963 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=vimars%3AbaseChart&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A198&WIDTH=5710&HEIGHT=2855&BBOX=43.14008315823114%2C27.77344470081666%2C43.25146798108994%2C27.996214346534245'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
2020-02-13 14:31:46,963 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=vimars%3AbaseChart&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A198&WIDTH=5710&HEIGHT=2855&BBOX=43.14008315823114%2C27.77344470081666%2C43.25146798108994%2C27.996214346534245'; against '/'
2020-02-13 14:31:46,963 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=vimars%3AbaseChart&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A198&WIDTH=5710&HEIGHT=2855&BBOX=43.14008315823114%2C27.77344470081666%2C43.25146798108994%2C27.996214346534245'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
2020-02-13 14:31:46,963 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=vimars%3AbaseChart&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A198&WIDTH=5710&HEIGHT=2855&BBOX=43.14008315823114%2C27.77344470081666%2C43.25146798108994%2C27.996214346534245'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
2020-02-13 14:31:46,964 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=vimars%3AbaseChart&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A198&WIDTH=5710&HEIGHT=2855&BBOX=43.14008315823114%2C27.77344470081666%2C43.25146798108994%2C27.996214346534245'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
2020-02-13 14:31:46,964 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=vimars%3AbaseChart&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A198&WIDTH=5710&HEIGHT=2855&BBOX=43.14008315823114%2C27.77344470081666%2C43.25146798108994%2C27.996214346534245'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
2020-02-13 14:31:46,964 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=vimars%3AbaseChart&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A198&WIDTH=5710&HEIGHT=2855&BBOX=43.14008315823114%2C27.77344470081666%2C43.25146798108994%2C27.996214346534245'; against '/rest/**'
2020-02-13 14:31:46,964 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=vimars%3AbaseChart&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A198&WIDTH=5710&HEIGHT=2855&BBOX=43.14008315823114%2C27.77344470081666%2C43.25146798108994%2C27.996214346534245'; against '/gwc/rest/**'
2020-02-13 14:31:46,964 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=vimars%3AbaseChart&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A198&WIDTH=5710&HEIGHT=2855&BBOX=43.14008315823114%2C27.77344470081666%2C43.25146798108994%2C27.996214346534245'; against '/**'
2020-02-13 14:31:46,964 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Request matched by universal pattern '/**'
2020-02-13 14:31:46,965 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /wms, QueryString: SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=vimars%3AbaseChart&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi%3A198&WIDTH=5710&HEIGHT=2855&BBOX=43.14008315823114%2C27.77344470081666%2C43.25146798108994%2C27.996214346534245 with /**
2020-02-13 14:31:46,967 TRACE [org.geoserver.ows.OWSHandlerMapping] - Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher@289a9fba] and 1 interceptors
2020-02-13 14:31:46,967 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2020-02-13 14:31:46,968 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES
2020-02-13 14:31:46,968 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing lndare style for vimars:lndare
2020-02-13 14:31:46,968 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing depare style for vimars:depare
2020-02-13 14:31:46,968 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing buuare style for vimars:buaare
2020-02-13 14:31:46,968 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing berths style for vimars:berths
2020-02-13 14:31:46,968 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing soundg style for vimars:soundg
2020-02-13 14:31:46,969 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing achare style for vimars:achare
2020-02-13 14:31:46,969 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing achbrt style for vimars:achbrt
2020-02-13 14:31:46,969 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing boylat style for vimars:boylat
2020-02-13 14:31:46,969 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing boysaw style for vimars:boysaw
2020-02-13 14:31:46,969 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing boyspp style for vimars:boyspp
2020-02-13 14:31:46,969 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing lights style for vimars:lights
2020-02-13 14:31:46,970 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms] - setting up map
2020-02-13 14:31:46,972 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - setting up 5710x2855 image
2020-02-13 14:31:46,975 DEBUG [org.vfny.geoserver.responses.wms.map] - setting to transparent
2020-02-13 14:31:47,245 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getMap
    Angle = 0.0
    BaseUrl = http://10.10.10.12:8080/geoserver/
    Bbox = SRSEnvelope[43.14008315823114 : 43.25146798108994, 27.77344470081666 : 27.996214346534245]
    BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
    Buffer = 0
    CQLFilter = null
    Crs = GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
  AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
    Elevation = []
    Env = {}
    Exceptions = SE_XML
    FeatureId = null
    FeatureVersion = null
    Filter = null
    Format = image/png
    FormatOptions = {DPI=198}
    Get = true
    Height = 2855
    Interpolations = []
    Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@a03f3c9d, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@ea5adf0a, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@9b0891e9, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@80b316bf, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@1534f817, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@47cdc001, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@47ce3631, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@9222745c, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@9225a352, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@9225dac8, org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@97e47fd2]
    MaxFeatures = null
    Palette = null
    RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetMap, FORMAT=image/png, CRS=EPSG:4326, FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:198, BBOX=43.14008315823114,27.77344470081666,43.25146798108994,27.996214346534245, VERSION=1.3.0, STYLES=, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=5710, HEIGHT=2855, TRANSPARENT=true, LAYERS=vimars:baseChart}
    RemoteOwsType = null
    RemoteOwsURL = null
    Request = GetMap
    RequestCharset = UTF-8
    ScaleMethod = null
    Sld = null
    SldBody = null
    SldVersion = null
    SortBy = null
    SortByArrays = null
    SRS = urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326
    StartIndex = null
    StyleBody = null
    StyleFormat = sld
    Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=lndare], StyleImpl[ name=depare], StyleImpl[ name=buuare], StyleImpl[ name=berths], StyleImpl[ name=soundg], StyleImpl[ name=achare], StyleImpl[ name=achbrt], StyleImpl[ name=boylat], StyleImpl[ name=boysaw], StyleImpl[ name=boyspp], StyleImpl[ name=lights]]
    StyleUrl = null
    StyleVersion = null
    Tiled = false
    TilesOrigin = null
    Time = []
    Transparent = true
    ValidateSchema = false
    Version = 1.3.0
    ViewParams = null
    Width = 5710
2020-02-13 14:31:47,247 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Writing png image ...
2020-02-13 14:31:47,316 DEBUG [org.geoserver.filters] - Not compressing output for mimetype: image/png
2020-02-13 14:31:47,540 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - Writing png image ... done!
2020-02-13 14:31:47,541 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2020-02-13 14:31:52,075 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 52-1.IFormSubmitListener-form'; against '/web/**'
2020-02-13 14:31:52,075 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 52-1.IFormSubmitListener-form with /web/**
2020-02-13 14:31:52,079 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-02-13 14:31:52,079 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-02-13 14:31:52,079 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-02-13 14:31:52,079 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-02-13 14:31:52,079 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 59 locking in mode READ
2020-02-13 14:31:52,079 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 59 got the lock in mode READ
2020-02-13 14:31:52,080 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 59 locking in mode READ
2020-02-13 14:31:52,080 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 59 releasing the lock in mode READ
2020-02-13 14:31:52,082 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2020-02-13 14:31:52,090 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: lines=1000'; against '/web/**'
2020-02-13 14:31:52,090 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: lines=1000 with /web/**
2020-02-13 14:31:52,093 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-02-13 14:31:52,093 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-02-13 14:31:52,093 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-02-13 14:31:52,093 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-02-13 14:31:52,093 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 59 locking in mode READ
2020-02-13 14:31:52,093 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 59 got the lock in mode READ
```

Comment: Please look in the log files and add the actual query being run to your question using the [edit] button. You may need to turn logging up to developer to see the query.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PostGIS simplification flag only controls whether simplification happens at the database level. If that is disabled, then simplification is done inside the rendering engine (in memory), that one cannot be disabled.

Can you please share a screenshot of the "huge problem", maybe side by side with another map done with a different too, e.g., QGIS?

Comment: [Here's a comparison between QGIS and GeoServer](https://paste.pics/81YF1). If it's worth anything , QGIS shows a local file whereas GeoServer has that file imported into a PostGIS database. When using pgAdmin to preview the geometry columns of the same geometries , they're not simplified so it's not a case of ogr2ogr messing the geometries up.

Comment: Nah, the simplification may throw away geometries that are smaller than a pixel, but never something that big. I'd verify it in other ways, like, pick the layer in question and look at it with the "polygon" style, do they appear?

Comment: It didn't occur to me that it could actually be a styling/rendering issue since I could see the polygon becoming less simplified the more I zoomed in.
It turns out I mis-managed the layer ordering in the layer group I was using this in , and I had another layer covering it up.

Thanks for your time !